# Applications of Freiman's theorem?

Tags: mathematics-education, additive-combinatorics, inverse-problems

What are some interesting applications of [Freiman's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiman%27s_theorem) or, better-yet, its recent generalizations (eg [Green-Ruzsa](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505198v2.pdf)) that could be included in a graduate course in additive combinatorics?

I'm looking for an application or two which would take no more than a total of two weeks to present in class. Nathanson includes a proof which relies on Freiman's theorem that if a sufficiently large subset of the integers contains many three term arithmetic progressions, then it contains a long arithmetic progression. This application meets my criteria, but is so old at this point --  surely newer and more interesting applications are out there.

Comment: This is not exactly additive combinatorics, but a surprising application nevertheless. I learned from a talk by Figalli that he and Jerison proved a stability result, of Brunn-Minkowski type, for sumsets in $\mathbb R^n$; the proof is done by induction on the dimension, and the basic step $n=1$ is done by discretisation, splitting a subset of $\mathbb R$ in $p$ parts for a large _prime_ $p$, and then applying Freiman or some qualitatively equivalent theorem. See https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/figalli/papers/Quantitative%20stability%20for%20sumsets%20in%20Rn.pdf for the details.